# Caching preprocessed data for ML in spark/pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I would like a ML pipeline like this:

1. `raw_data = spark.read....()`
2. `data = time_consuming_data_transformation(raw_data, preprocessing_params)`
3. `model = fit_model(data)`
4. `evaluate(model, data)`

Can I cache/persist data somehow after step 2, so when I run my spark app again, the data won't have to be transformed again? Ideally, I would like the cache to be automatically invalidated when the original data or transformation code (computing graph, preprocessing_params) change.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I cache/persist data somehow after step 2, so when I run my spark app again, the data won't have to be transformed again?

You can of course:

```
data = time_consuming_data_transformation(raw_data, preprocessing_params).cache()
```

but if you're data is non-static, it is always better to write data to persistent storage:

```
time_consuming_data_transformation(raw_data, preprocessing_params).write.save(...)
data = spark.read.load(...)
```

It is more expensive than cache, but prevents hard to detect inconsistencies when data changes.

> Ideally, I would like the cache to be automatically invalidated when the original data

No. Unless it is a streaming program (and learning on streams is not so trivial) Spark doesn't monitor changes in the source.

> or transformation code (computing graph, preprocessing_params) change.

It is not clear for me how things change but it is probablly not something that Spark will solve for you. You might need some event driven or reactive components.